# Calculating the average points assigned to arrays java

Tags: java

I have a homework which asks me to create a method which returns a total after calculating the average of points assigned to arrays.

for example :

Question 1 : costs 3 points

Question 2 : costs 1 point

Question 3 : costs 2 points

Number of total of points is = 6 points.

So we have, for example, question 1 answered right, question 2 answered wrong, question 3 answered right. We have then a score of 5/6. And if the Total is equal to 100, we have : 5*100/6. this method returns total : 83.3...

I have started a partial code, something like that, I have no idea what to do and where to start:

```
public double finalNote(int total) throw ArithmeticException(){

    String [] questions;
    questions = new String [] {"questions 1", "questions 2", "questions 3" };


    total = 0;

    boolean estCorrect = false;



    if (total <= 0){

    throw new ArithmeticException();

}


for (int i = 0 ; i < questions.length; i++){

} 
    return total;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey May5, you should try a little harder on this problem. You aren't going to learn anything if you are given the answer. This question isn't going to be received well here.

Comment: @SamOrozco is completely correct. At StackOverflow, we're here to help you debug code that you have already written, not write it for you. The only way to learn is by doing the work yourself. If you do create an algorithm to complete this, but encounter a roadblock, that would be the time to possibly create a question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I totally agree. the thing is i dont know how to assign the points to the questions. However calculating points, making sums and calculate the average, these I can do easily. i will update the code gradually. thanks anyway !!!

Answer (score 0):

Start with declaring variables to hold the value of each question and setting them to their points, then using (an) if-else statement(s) to control whether each was right or wrong. You won't need arithmetic errors, don't over-complicate the question.